# what's the difference between a ref edge and non-ref edge in tensorflow?

Tags: tensorflow

As the title says, I'm wondering about the conceptual difference between  a "ref edge" and "non-ref edge" in TensorFlow.

I'm reading the graph partitioning algorithm in TensorFlow.
Here ([line 826 of `graph_partition.cc`](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/1708b92bb923e420d746a56baafc7d4ddcd5e05e/tensorflow/core/graph/graph_partition.cc#L825)) is the comment which mentions 
the "non-ref edge":

```
 825   // For a node dst, 'ref_recvs' remembers the recvs introduced by a ref
 826   // edge to dst. 'ref_control_inputs' remembers the inputs by a non-ref
 827   // edge to dst. We will add a control edge for every pair in
 828   // (ref_recvs x ref_control_inputs).
 829   std::vector<NodeDef*> ref_recvs;
 830   std::vector<string> ref_control_inputs;
```

Can someone explain the difference more clearly? Thanks very much.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In TensorFlow, most edges are "non-ref" edges, which means that the value flowing along that edge is a constant. If you think of a vertex (operation) in a TensorFlow graph as a function, you can think of a non-ref edge as representing a function argument that is [passed by value](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Evaluation_strategy#Call_by_value) in a conventional programming language like C or C++. For example, the inputs to and outputs from the operation `z = tf.matmul(x, y)` are all non-ref edges.

A "ref edge" in TensorFlow allows the value flowing along that edge to be mutated. Continuing the function analogy, a ref edge represents a function argument that is [passed by reference](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Evaluation_strategy#Call_by_reference) (from which we take the name "ref" edge). The most common use of ref edges is in the current internal implementation of [`tf.Variable`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/Variable): the internal [Variable kernel](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/1708b92bb923e420d746a56baafc7d4ddcd5e05e/tensorflow/core/kernels/variable_ops.h) owns a mutable buffer, and outputs a reference to that buffer on a ref edge. Operations such as [`tf.assign(var, val)`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/assign) expect their `var` argument to be passed along ref edge, because they need to mutate the value in `var`.

The graph partitioning algorithm treats ref edges specially because they correspond to values that could change as the graph executes. Since a non-ref edge is a constant value, TensorFlow can assume that all non-ref edges out of the same operation that cross between two devices can be combined into a single edge, which saves on network/memory bandwidth. Since the value on a ref edge can change (e.g. if a variable is updated in the middle of a step), TensorFlow must be careful not to combine the edges, so that the remote device can see the new value. By analogy with C/C++, the TensorFlow graph partitioner treats a ref-edge as representing a [`volatile`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Volatile_(computer_programming)) variable, for the purposes of optimization.

Finally, as you can tell from the amount of explanation above, ref edges are quite complicated, and there is an ongoing effort to remove them from the TensorFlow execution model. The replacement is "resource-typed edges", which allow non-tensor values to flow along an edge (unifying variables, queues, readers, and other complex objects in TensorFlow), and explicit operations that take a variable resource as input and read its value (as a non-ref output edge). The implementation of the new "resource variables" can be seen [here in Python](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/1708b92bb923e420d746a56baafc7d4ddcd5e05e/tensorflow/python/ops/resource_variable_ops.py) and [here in C++](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/1708b92bb923e420d746a56baafc7d4ddcd5e05e/tensorflow/core/kernels/resource_variable_ops.cc).

Comment: Does the resource-typed edges improve the performance ? Or just avoid the complication of original design?  and thanks for your answer.

Comment: They should be neutral for performance at first, but by simplifying the memory model (and making more tensors read-only) it should be possible to optimize the graphs further in the future.

Comment: I'm confused about making more tensors read-only indeed. As I know(from stackoverflow), there are many Out-of-memory case happened while people run their training. And making more tensors read-only indicate more memory used. :-)