# Tensorflow: Incompatible types for dataset.map() in tf.contrib.data

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow-datasets

When using a hash table lookup with `tf.contrib.Dataset.map()`, it fails with the following error:

`TypeError: In op 'hash_table_Lookup', input types ([tf.string, tf.string, tf.int32]) are not compatible with expected types ([tf.string_ref, tf.string, tf.int32])`

Code to reproduce:

```
from __future__ import absolute_import
from __future__ import division
from __future__ import print_function

import tensorflow as tf

initializer = tf.contrib.lookup.KeyValueTensorInitializer(
    ['one', 'two', 'three'], [1, 2, 3])
hash_table = tf.contrib.lookup.HashTable(initializer, -1)

tensor = tf.convert_to_tensor(['one', 'two', 'three'])
dataset = tf.contrib.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(tensor)
dataset = dataset.map(lambda k: hash_table.lookup(k))
```

It complains about `tf.string_ref` and `tf.string` being incompatible.

It's strange that it expects a `tf.string_ref` and not a `tf.string`. Does anyone know why this is the case and what I can do about it?

The issues is related to `table_ref` being `tf.string_ref` [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/r1.2/tensorflow/contrib/lookup/lookup_ops.py#L232).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a bug that was fixed in TensorFlow 1.3. If you are using TensorFlow 1.2, the following workaround should work:

```
from __future__ import absolute_import
from __future__ import division
from __future__ import print_function

import tensorflow as tf

# Use internal library implementation of `lookup_ops` in TensorFlow 1.2.
from tensorflow.python.ops import lookup_ops
initializer = lookup_ops.KeyValueTensorInitializer(
    ['one', 'two', 'three'], [1, 2, 3])
hash_table = lookup_ops.HashTable(initializer, -1)

tensor = tf.convert_to_tensor(['one', 'two', 'three'])
dataset = tf.contrib.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(tensor)
dataset = dataset.map(lambda k: hash_table.lookup(k))
```

Up until TensorFlow 1.2, the `tf.contrib.lookup` library used ["reference types"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37959933/3574081) to represent the lookup tables, whereas in the internal library (used to implement `tf.contrib.lookup` from 1.3 onwards) the more modern and compatible ["resource types"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42600232/3574081) are used.